# UIButton not responding after click swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am doing a Four in a row game. every spot on my board is a UIButton, I am trying to make a func that will check if the user can insert a chip to the pressed button, when my func return false for one button, the button is not responding any more... thanks
        here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
//player1 = red, player2 = blue
var activePlayer = 1;
var activeGame = true;
var gameState:[Int] = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
let winningOptions = [[0,1,2,3]]; //just one option for now
@IBAction func btnClicked(_ gridBtns : UIButton){
    print(gridBtns.tag);
    let activePosition = gridBtns.tag - 1;
    if gameState[activePosition] == 0 && activeGame{
        gridBtns.center = CGPoint(x: gridBtns.center.x , y: gridBtns.center.y - 500);
        gameState[activePosition] = activePlayer;
        if okToPutChip(gridBtns){
            if activePlayer == 1{
                gridBtns.setImage(UIImage(named: "red_chip.png"), for: []);
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                    gridBtns.center = CGPoint(x: gridBtns.center.x, y: gridBtns.center.y + 500)
                });
                activePlayer = 2;
            }else{
                gridBtns.setImage(UIImage(named: "blue_chip.png"), for: []);
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                    gridBtns.center = CGPoint(x: gridBtns.center.x, y: gridBtns.center.y + 500)
                });
                activePlayer = 1;
            }
        }else{
            print("button will not show this again beacuse its not responding");
        }
        for option in winningOptions{
            if gameState[option[0]] != 0 && gameState[option[0]] == gameState[option[1]] && gameState[option[1]] == gameState[option[2]] && gameState[option[2]] == gameState[option[3]]{
                print("winner!!!!")
                activeGame = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
//my func to check if there is no chips blow this position
func okToPutChip(_ gridBtns : UIButton)->Bool{
    let position = gridBtns.tag-1;
    print("********position = \(position)")
    if position < 35 && gameState[position+7] == 0{
        print("now return false")
        return false;
    }else if position < 35 && gameState[position+7] != 0{
        print("here???")
        return true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: the grid is 7x6

Comment: Is your `print(gridBtns.tag)` line executing?

Comment: BTW, semicolons are not required in Swift, and you should not include them. The only time you need one is if you put 2 statements on the same line (and you shouldn't do that.)

Comment: Not responding how?... Does the app freeze/crash? Does the button just do nothing?

Comment: It's seems what you are 'locking' you button with `activeGame`, please check you wining conditions

Comment: print(gridBtns.tag) is executing, everything is working fine, the problem is if the func return false, the same button is not responding any more and I cannot put a chip there, the line: print(gridBtns.tag) is NOT executing

Comment: found my problem , I moved the line gridBtns.center = CGPoint(x: gridBtns.center.x , y: gridBtns.center.y - 500), after the line: if okToPutChip(gridBtns)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are experiencing Auto Layout conflicts by changing the center property directly. You might find some interesting warnings in the log. UIButton for some reason in particular doesn't like being moved around manually when Auto Layout is present.

Either turn off Auto Layout on your storyboard file OR adjust the layout constraints of the button instead of modifying its center property. There are a few tutorials you can look for on how to animate layout changes.

OR you can do the sleazy thing:

Use `UIView.animate(withDuration:,animations:,completion:)` and in the `completion` closure do the following:

```
let superview = gridBtns.superview
gridBtns.removeFromSuperview()
gridBtns.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
superview.addSubview(gridBtns)
```

Hope that helps.